# separating string of characters and int from a input string in c++

Tags: c++, string, atoi

I am trying to sort integers and strings from an input string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char x[10];
    int y;
    printf("string: ");
    scanf("%s",x);
    y=atoi(x);
    printf("\n %d", y);
    getchar();
    getchar(); }
```

suppose the input is 123abc1
using atoi i could extract 123 from the input string, my question now is how do i extract abc1?

I want to store abc1 on a separate character variable.

input: 123abc1
output: x = 123, some char variable = abc1

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to use the C programming language concepts, then consider using `strtol` intead of `atoi`. It will let you know what character did it stop at:

Also, never use `%s` in a `scanf`, always specify the buffer size (minus one, since %s will add a '\0' after storing your input)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("string: ");
    char x[10];
    scanf("%9s",x);
    char *s;
    int y = strtol(x, &s, 10);
    printf("String parsed as:\ninteger: %d\nremainder of the string: %s\n",y, s);
}
```

test: https://ideone.com/uCop8

In C++, if that tag was not a mistake, there are simpler approaches, such as stream I/O.

For example,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "string: ";
    int x;
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> x >> s;
    std::cout << "String parsed as:\ninteger: " << x << '\n'
              << "remainder of the string: " << s << '\n';
}
```

test: https://ideone.com/dWYPx

Answer (score 0):

If that's the way you want to go, then after extracting the number convert it back to its textual representation and that string length will tell you were to find the start of the string. So for your particular example:

```
char* x = "123abc1"
atoi( x ) -> 123;
itoa/sprintf( 123 ) -> "123", length 3
x + 3 -> "abc1"
```

Can't you just do it with a single scanf?

```
scanf( "%d%s", &y, z );
```

Comment: I think it should be `atoi` and not `itoa`